# What is the physical setup for using multiple Azure Kinects on one pc?

Tags: azure, kinect

Riffing off of this question: [sync and stitch multiple kinect azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996858/sync-and-stitch-multiple-kinect-azure)

I am interested in the **PHYSICAL SETUP** for using multiple Azure Kinects. My particular installation requires the use of three Azure Kinects, all placed on the same wall and spaced about 10'(3m) apart. The goal is to use depth data to generate content on 3 displays on the wall.

Questions:
1. What are the limitations of connecting more than one kinect to a single computer?
2. How do you connect and work with more than one kinect with a single computer?
3. What limitations exist for extending the USB cable from the kinect to the computer?
4. Any limitations in using a USB 3.1 4-port hub with 3 Azure Kinects?
5. Is it better to keep one kinect per computer? If so, any recommendations for a computer solely dedicated to grabbing depth data and making it available over a network for creating multi-kinect installations?

Furthermore, I found this brief on extending Azure Kinect cables. I was hoping to use the 4-port fiber extender on towards the bottom. https://www.newnex.com/technology-azure-kinect-extension.php

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with multiple virtual machines on the same server...